# ¿Como puedo eliminar los saltos de linea que me genera un String?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Este seria  el código que me produce el salto de linea.

```
miString = miString.replaceFirst("texto a reemplazar", "");
miString = misString.trim();
```

Lo que me ocurre es que al guardarlo en el .txt me genera ese salto de linea tan molesto. Necesito borrar de alguna manera saltos de linea. 
Probe estos códigos y nada....

```
misString= misString.replaceFirst("\n", "");
misString= misString.replaceAll("\\n\\r", "");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
misString= misString.replaceFirst("\n", "");
```

Como el nombre (y el javadoc) de la función indica, solo te reemplazará la primera ocurrencia...

```
misString= misString.replaceAll("\\n\\r", "");
```

Esto replaza todas las ocurrencias, pero el problema es la cadena que buscas.

`\` se usa para marcar carácteres de escape (*escape characters*) que representan símbolos no imprimibles mediante símbolos imprimibles. `\n` es un carácter de escape que representa una nueva línea.

`\\` se usa para "escapar" la `\` de forma que se sepa que representa el carácter `\` y no que es una parte de un carácter de escape.

Así que `\\n` se lee como "carácter `\` seguido de carácter `n`", no como "nueva línea".

Lo más sencillo, para eliminarlos todos independientemente de la codificación de fin de línea (varía según el sistema operativo), sería

```
misString= misString.replaceAll("(\n|\r)", "");
```

Otra opción es usar `System.getProperty("line.separator")` que directamente te da el valor del separador de línea usado por el sistema operativo:

```
misString= misString.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator", ""));
```